# C# attributes used for information or to import extern functions?

Tags: c#

I'm a bit confused about C#'s use of attributes. At first I thought it was simply used to give program code additional information through the use of the [`[Obsolete]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute). Now I find that [`[Dllimport]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute) can be used to import a dynamic linked library and its functions. Can attributes import .exe files and other kind of files?

A last question, for programmers working in C# every day, how much do you use attributes, and do you use it for anything else than extending information and importing dll's?

Comment: I use attributes *tons*; a great example is for providing information to libraries - for example to tell an OEM what the column is called, or to tell a serializer how a particular property should be treated. Or to tell the JIT not to ever inline a particular method, etc.

Comment: Can't effectively do unit testing without attributes to decorate test classes and methods or to pass test data into tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply said, attributes are just metadata attached to classes or methods, at the very base.

The *compiler*, however, reads through your code, and runs specific actions for specific attributes it encounters while doing so, hardcoded into it. E.g., when it finds a [`DllImportAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute) on a method, it will resolve it to an external symbol (again, this is a very simplified explanation).
When it finds an [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute), it emits a warning of deprecation.

Your own attributes (which [you can create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes) with a class inheriting from the `Attribute` base class) will not have an effect on the default compiler. But you (or other libraries) can also scan for them at *runtime*, opening up many possibilities and leading to your second question:

I typically use them to do meta programming. For example, imagine a custom network server handling packets of a specific format, implemented in different classes. Each packet format is recognized by reading an integer value. Now I need to find the correct class to instantiate for that integer.

- I could do that with a switch..case or dictionary mapping integer -> packet which I extend every time I add a packet, but that is ugly since I have to touch code possibly far away from the actual Packet class whenever I add or delete a packet. I may not even know about the switch or dictionary in case the server is implemented in another assembly than my packets (modularity / extensibility)!
- Instead, I create a custom `PacketAttribute`, storing an integer property set via the attribute, and decorate all my Packet classes with it. The server only has to scan through my assembly types at startup (via reflection) and build a dictionary of integer -> packet pairs automatically. Of course I could scan my assembly every time I need a packet, but that's probably a bit slow performance-wise.

There are APIs which are much more attribute heavy, like [controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing): You map full request URLs to methods in handler classes with them, which then execute the server code. Even URL parameters are mapped to parameters in that way.

*Debuggers* can also make use of attributes. For example, decorating a class with the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute) lets you provide a custom string displayed for the instances of the class when inspecting them in Visual Studio, which has a specific format and can directly show the values of important members.

You can see, attributes can be very powerful if utilized nicely. The comments give some more references! :)

Comment: I would add that in addition to attributes recognized by the compiler and custom attributes, there are attributes recognized by the framework at runtime, e.g. the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) used by MVC.

Comment: Good answer: just to add - the JIT also reads lots of attributes, as do a lot of BCL types, and popular libraries. Attributes are great. `[Yay]`

Comment: Bookmarked!

Cannot stress enough how glad I am for this information right here. Been at this all night and went through countless of tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your questions, they are also used, for example, in setting validation and display attributes for both client and server side use in a web application. For example:

```
[Display(Name = "Person's age")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Persons's age is required")]
[RangeCheck(13, 59, ErrorMessage = "The age must be between 13 and 59")]
 public int? PersonsAgeAtBooking { get; set; }
```

Or to decorate enums for use in display

```
public enum YesNoOnlyEnum
{
    [Description("Yes")]
    Yes = 1,
    [Description("No")]
    No = 2
}
```

There are many other uses.